# Android Creating Navigation Drawer Dynamically

Tags: android

I want to create a navigation drawer dynamically. I fetch the strings from the database and add to a string list.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject json_data;
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String toAppend = json_data.getString("name");
        names.add(toAppend); 
}
```

What should I do for the next step for adding in ListView navigation drawer?

Answer (score 1):

You can get help from these links to know what steps to follow-

http://hmkcode.com/android-creating-a-navigation-drawer/
    http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/28/navigation-drawer-android/

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I want to create a dynamic navigation drawer. I created one like these links but I fetch the item names from the database. Firstly, I add these item names to an ArrayList then I have to use ArrayAdapter for adding ListView. I think, I do a mistake for this step. I think, i can't convert ArrayList to Array for ArrayAdapter because or I overlook something. I get an error also : NullPointerException:storage==null

Comment: Not exactly, I have two classes; I fetch the datas from database in the first one then I try to use these datas (item names) in the second class for adding item names to the navigation drawer ListView. Something gets wrong :(

Comment: @elfoz post your full code with errors hope someone helps you.

Comment: mPlanetTitles = names.toArray(mPlanetTitles); I think, this line reason for the error.

Comment: @elfoz post your full code with errors hope someone helps you.

Comment: I realized that the error is about: "Return value from AsyncTask class onPostExecute method" . I read something about it but it's not clear yet for me.